# Starting javascript function due to URL Link in "Browser"

Tags: javascript, excel, wininet, vba

I'm using wininet to get the sourcecode from some homepages, afterwards I analyse that for some information. I use VB in Excel to do that. 
All of this is working fine, but now I want to get information from a special page.

I have to open this page and click a link to go to the side with the wanted information. 
My problem is, that this link is a javascript function. So my question: is it possible to open a side and start the javascript function due to a URL?

I use following VB Function:

```
'API-Deklarationen: 
Private Declare Sub InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" ( _ 
    ByVal hInet As Long) 
Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _ 
    ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long, _ 
    ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _ 
    ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Function InternetOpenUrlA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _ 
    ByVal hOpen As Long, ByVal sUrl As String, _ 
    ByVal sHeaders As String, ByVal lLength As Long, _ 
    ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Long 
Private Declare Sub InternetReadFile Lib "wininet.dll" ( _ 
    ByVal hFile As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, _ 
    ByVal lNumBytesToRead As Long, lNumberOfBytesRead As Long) 

'Enumeration für Internet: 
Public Enum InternetOpenType 
  IOTPreconfig = 0 
  IOTDirect = 1 
  IOTProxy = 3 
End Enum 


Public s As String 

Public Function OpenURL( _ 
    ByVal URL As String, _ 
    Optional ByVal OpenType As InternetOpenType = IOTPreconfig _ 
  ) As String 
  Const INET_RELOAD = &H80000000 
  Dim hInet As Long 
  Dim hURL As Long 
  Dim Buffer As String * 2048 
  Dim Bytes As Long 

  'Inet-Connection öffnen: 
  hInet = InternetOpenA( _ 
      "VB-Tec:INET", OpenType, _ 
      vbNullString, vbNullString, 0) 
  hURL = InternetOpenUrlA( _ 
      hInet, URL, vbNullString, 0, INET_RELOAD, 0) 

  'Daten sammeln: 
  Do 
    InternetReadFile hURL, Buffer, Len(Buffer), Bytes 
    If Bytes = 0 Then Exit Do 
    OpenURL = OpenURL & Left$(Buffer, Bytes) 
  Loop 

  'Inet-Connection schließen: 
  InternetCloseHandle hURL 
  InternetCloseHandle hInet 
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Try to use the InternetExplorer-Control, it provides all you need:
ability to navigate and scripting-access to the document.

[InternetExplorer-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Document-Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752052%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)